# import and restore 500MB Magento SQL database backup file into new server

Tags: database, magento, restore

I've spend whole day trying to restore a 499MB .SQL magento database backup file into a new server. I have tried importing into another PC offline but im getting same error `Unknown command '\9' and '\a'`, im trying to restore the .SQL file using the following command - `mysql -u -p databasename < backup.sql`

I have tried Bigdump script but no success. The database file is too large it won't even open up on my pc.

Is there any other way to restore a database backup file of this size into a new server ? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: Strange characters appearing on opening .SQL backup file.[strange characters in .sql file](http://www.filedropper.com/magentodbbackuperrornotepad)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the character sets of the databases match up. eg: `mysql --default-character-set=utf8 database < databasedump.sql`

Comment: i did that as well, i managed to open up the .SQL file in notepad++, the line number where the error occurs has some strange characters, i have no idea from where those contents come. Is it because i didnt backup the database properly ? I backup the database through PHPMYADMIN.

Comment: Do you have binary blobs in your database? If so you might want to try dumping the database with --hex-blob option.

Comment: ok, i have to try that option, Phpmyadmin has option to binary columns in hexadecimal notation which i chose during the backup